# Doctrine Query Builder using Array

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have an array of id:

```
Id_array; //array(2) { [0]=> int(9) [1]=> int(10) }
```

I simply want to select the users using Id_array;
I managed to do this when I don't have an array but just an integer:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.id = ?1');
$query->setParameter(1, 9); // I tested the value 9 here
$users = $query->getResult();
```

How can I fetch all the users that correspond to Id_array?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Or without the query builder:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.id IN (:id)');
$query->setParameter('id', array(1, 9));
$users = $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 9):

In case someone runs into something similar, I used the query builder, The key point is to use the IN statement.

```
//...
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');
$qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('u.id', ':my_array'))
->setParameter('my_array', $Id_array);
```

Comment: your solution works best because it handles strings too, the accepted answer works only with integers

Comment: Above didn't work for me. I had to do `setParameter('my_array', $Id_array, Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY)`. Maybe because I use DBAL query builder, not ORM one.

Answer (score 7):

On doctrine 2 is implemented by the repository now since 2.1 or 2.2

```
findBy(array('id' => array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thx!