# doctrine dql/queryBuilder with a foreach or array in parameters

Tags: php, foreach, doctrine-orm, query-builder, dql

In my symfony aplication, I recover a variable as a string by my ajax script.

This variable looks like this:

```
$slug = "1-2-3-4-4-5-6-7" /* it could more*/
$vars = explode('-',$slug ); /*push the $slug string in an array */

/* recover all value of the array */
foreach ($vars as $var) {
      echo $var;
    }
```

Now I need to use this foreach in a `dql` or a `query builder` because all $var are ids of an entity and i need to pass all this value to get the right result.

How can I make a query with an array of parameter or make a foreach in doctrine query builder ?

I have already try something this in a queryBuilder method:

```
->setParameters("id" => $vars);
```

it returns me an error : `SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

I try this too in the queryBuilder:

```
->setParameters(array('id' => array($vars)));
```

Here I have no error, but it does not return the good result. Indeed I have **only one** result in database if there are many ids.

Comment: This has been [asked and answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555207/doctrine-query-builder-using-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996921/doctrine2-querybuilder-must-return-only-result-matching-with-array-values-ids/34999636#34999636).

I created a more complex query in order to answer to all condition:

> array is empty
>
> array contains only 1 value
>
> array contains many values

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the id is within a certain set of given ids you can use `IN`.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->addSelect('u')
        ->innerJoin('s.field','u')
        ->where("u.id IN(:ids)")
        ->setParameter('ids', array_values($ids));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ->setParameter('ids', $ids). where $ids is the array of ids

Comment: see my edit, in fact if I use `setParameters("ids" => $ids)` I have an error of SQLState for the cardinality like `SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 1 column(s)`. As it is wrote, the dql does not accept an array here.

Comment: ->where('topic.user IN (:userIds)')
    ->setParameter('userIds', $userIds);