# doctrine2 queryBuilder must return only result matching with array values (ids): 0/Null and/or One and/or Many id(s) have to return One result

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder, dql

I have an array of collection named `$configurations`. This array matches of my Entity `Configuration.php` connected to `Product.php` as a `ManyToMany`. Now I have another entity named `WorkType.php` which is connected too to `Configuration.php` by a `ManyToMany`.

The goal is to recover the product who has `O/Null` or `Many` configurations for the current work type.

By default I have a product without configurations, but user could choose by checkboxes a `O/Null` or `One` or `Many` configurations available for a work type.

So I created this queryBuilder in my `ProductRepository.php`:

```
public function getProductByManyConfig($slug, $configurations)
  {

    $queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

    $queryBuilder->select('p')
                 ->from('MyBundle', 'p')
                 ->join('p.workType', 'wt', 'WITH', 'wt.id = p.workType')
                 ->leftJoin('p.configurations','c');

    $queryBuilder->add('where', $queryBuilder->expr()->in('c', ':c'))
                 ->andWhere('wt.slug = :slug')
                 ->setParameters(array('slug'=> $slug, 'c'=> $configurations));

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()
                        ->getResult();
  }
```

It works, but the proble is that it returns me all product matching with the array of configurations I pass to the query.

For example if the array have the `id` **1** and **2** of `Configuration.php`, the query returns me the products matching with **configuration.id = 1**, **configuration.id = 2** and **configuration.id =1 and 2**.

> So I have 3 conditions to achieve, I need only one; e-g only the product which
>   containing all the configuration.id !

I only need to return the only one product containing the `ids` of `Configuration.php` passed into the array for the current `WorkType.php` !

This is my controller code:

```
$vars = array(); //containing all values I need for recover configurations properties

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$var = array_values($vars);

$configurations = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Configuration')->findByName($var);

foreach ($configurations as $conf) {
  $name = $conf->getName();
}

$slug = "the_right_database_correspondence";

$arrayProbuctConfig = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Product')->getProductByManyConfig($slug, $configurations);

// return of the view
```

As the choice of configurations could change, I need to create this dynamic method. How can I return the good result ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem with Doctrine2 recently and I came with that answer.

If you want all `Product` entities that are linked with **all** the configurations, you need to add a `where` condition for every configuration.

Considering your `$configurations` variable is an array of `Configuration` entities

```
$queryBuilder->select('p')
             ->from('MyBundle', 'p')
             ->join('p.workType', 'wt', 'WITH', 'wt.id = p.workType')
             ->leftJoin('p.configurations','c');

$queryBuilder->where('wt.slug = :slug')->setParameter('slug', $slug);

$nbConfs = count($configurations);
  for($i = 0; $i < count($configurations); $i++){
      $queryBuilder->andWhere(":conf{$i} MEMBER OF p.configurations")->setParameter("conf{$i}", $configurations[$i]);
  }

$queryBuilder
      ->having('COUNT(c.id) =:some_count')
      ->setParameter('some_count', $nbConfs);
```

I had to use a `for` loop to create different tokens (the string preceded by `:`), otherwise Doctrine doesn't add them to its internal collection of parameters.

Edit : Query modified to consider the case where you pass no configurations and want to get `Product`s that has no relations to `Configuration`s.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have not my code with me for now but count on me to try your suggestion. Thank you by the way !

Comment: your solution works well if I enter **2 or many Configurations**, but if my array contain **0/NULL or 1 Configuration** the query retuns me all product for the workType. So I need to fix that behavior.

Comment: @french_dev If I understood well your comment, I edited my code to limit to Product with no configuration when you pass an empty array. Concerning the case when you pass only one configuration, you should only have the Products connected to that Configuration.

Comment: the same as I told you before, your query works well, and now take care of the condition if the array is empty, but not if the array contain only one parameter. I am searching to create it ! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I found the solution thanks to you, I just edit your answer in order the solution is clear for other stackoverflow user.

Comment: @french_dev Ok now I fully understand what you tried to achieve. Nice collaborative work, thanks to you!