# Doctrine ORM many-to-many find all by taglist

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'v got simple m2m relation (book -> book_mark <- mark). I want to find item(book) by 1-2-3... x-count of tags(marks). Example: Book1 got these tags: [Mark1, Mark2, Mark3], Book2 got these tags: [Mark1, Mark3, Mark4]. Search list is [Mark1, Mark2]. I want to find only items, which have ALL tags from Search list, i.e. only Book1 in this example.

I have tried many ways and spend much time google it, but didn't find the answer.

Closest that I have is this:

```
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
    ->select('b, m')
    ->leftJoin('b.marks_list', 'm')
    ->andWhere(':marks_list MEMBER OF b.marks_list')
    ->setParameter('marks_list', $marksList)
    ->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```

But it's looking for books which have at least 1of the parameters, not all of them together

Next, I'v decided that I'm absolutely wrong and start thinking this way:

```
 public function findAllByMarksList(array $marksList)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
            ->select('b, m')
            ->leftJoin('b.marks_list', 'm');
        for ($i = 0; $i<count($marksList); $i++){
            $qb->andWhere('m.id in (:mark'.$i.')')
                ->setParameter('mark'.$i, $marksList[$i]);
        }
        return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    }
```

But here I faced another problem: This code is checking only 1 mark and then always returns an empty set if the number of parameters is more than 1.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, updated answer... It works (I have relation many to many between reviews and brands) it's the same situation, but for example if you have

Book 1 - mark1, mark2, mark3

Book 2 - mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4

with this code you will also find the book2, because all of it marks are in this list.

If you need to find book which haves only these 3 tags, you additionally need to add checking for count. (Count of tags = count of tagList)

```
    public function test()
{
    // just selecting for list for test

    $brandsList = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('b')
        ->from('ReviewsAdminBundle:Brands', 'b')
        ->where('b.id in (:brandIds)')
        ->setParameter('brandIds', [6,4])
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
    dump($brandsList);

    // query part

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
        ->select('r')
        ->leftJoin('r.brand', 'brands')
        ->where('r.published = 1');

    foreach ($brandsList as $oneBrand) {
        /** @var Brands $oneBrand */
        $identifier = $oneBrand->getId();
        $qb->andWhere(':brand'.$identifier.' MEMBER OF r.brand')
            ->setParameter('brand'.$identifier, $identifier);
    }

    dump($qb->getQuery()->getResult());
    die;
}
```

ps. Additionally you can check [doctrine2 queryBuilder must return only result matching with array values (ids): 0/Null and/or One and/or Many id(s) have to return One result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996921/doctrine2-querybuilder-must-return-only-result-matching-with-array-values-ids) (close to our situation)

*And, I think there's not better way of accomplishing this. Either you use multiple andWheres to compare id OR use MEMBER OF*

Comment: Ye, it's pretty far from my case. I think my code is absolutly wrong and there is should be the other way to do what I'm talking about. Anyway, thanks for your concern dude

Comment: So it didn't help you ? Maybe you can try to update question with more information. With current, it's a bit hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yep, I'll try to explain. As I said, I'v got m2m relation (book -> book_mark <- mark). I want to find item(book) by 1-2-3... x-count of tags(marks). Example: **Book1** got these tags: [_Mark1_, _Mark2_, Mark3], **Book2** got these tags: [_Mark1_, Mark3, Mark4]. **Search list** is [_Mark1_, _Mark2_]. I want to find only items, which have ALL tags from Search list, i.e. only **Book1** in this example

Comment: I actually replicated the problem  right now in some of my projects and I understood now. I will update the answer in moment. The key was you want to get ONLY book1 :).

Comment: Sounds like a blessing!

Comment: Check updated answer. If it helped, then accept as the right answer, so others can focus on other questions.

Comment: Oh god. It's works perfectly. I can't express all of my gratitude. <3